# jquery check html5 data value

Tags: jquery

How would I check what value a data attribute has? e.g.

```
<form data-after="closemodal">

<form data-after="refreshmodal">
```

I've tried doing it with:

```
if (form.data('after', 'closemodal'))
{
// close modal
}
else if (form.data('after', 'refreshmodal'))
{
// refresh modal
}
```

By the way `form` is a variable that stores the current form we are talking to

But it doesn't work? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your code there is setting those values. To check them you need to do:

```
if (form.data('after') == 'closemodal')
{
    // close modal
}
else if (form.data('after') == 'refreshmodal')
{
    // refresh modal
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing it will set the value of the data attribute.  You need to check it like this:

```
if (form.data('after') == 'closemodal')
{
// close modal
}
else if (form.data('after') == 'refreshmodal')
{
// refresh modal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is setting the data, not getting it:

```
form.data('after')
```

This will return the data value which you can then check for equality to some other string.

Answer (score 0):

you need a comparison

```
if(form.data("after")==="closemodal")
//do something
```